# Como automatizar una ventana emergente de explorer

Tags: selenium, ventana, internet-explorer-11, keypressevent, onkeypress

En el momento automatizo con selenium (page object)una pagina web que no me permite eliminar estas ventanas emergente para el momento controlo esta acción de la siguiente forma:

```
  try { driver.Keyboard.PressKey(Keys.Enter); } catch { }
```

pero igual no creo que sea la forma correcta pues no reconoce la ventana(por ser del navegador y no de la pagina)y la acción que hace es reventar con el presskey.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido!
¿Has intentado tratarlo como un alert? `var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert(); alert.Accept();`

Comment: Si,según entiendo los alert es cuando se genera una ventana emergente de la pagina,pero en este caso es un mensaje emergente del navegador

Comment: Entonces tendrias que ver las capabilities de navegador, no se si IE lo permite, pero Chrome o Firefox, tienen opciones de aceptar automaticamente todos las descargas y cosas asi